# Child passport and visa is getting expired prior to parent's

Tags: passport-renewals

I am a Pakistani citizen holding a Pakistani passport. My child has a valid Canadian visit visa on his passport and it is going to expire on Apr 2020. (Both passport and Visa) However my passport has a longer validity (both visa and passport).

My question is: How can my child stay longer than expiry? Do I need to renew his passport and re apply for his there in Canada or I need to fly back to Pakistan, renew his passport and apply new visitor visa?

Answer (score 1):

A visa normally does not extend beyond the passport's expiration date.

You can renew your child's passport in Canada. There is a long list of required documents on [this page](http://www.pakmission.ca/passport.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) of the Pakistani Embassy in Toronto. I'm not going to reproduce it here. I suspect that you cannot use the online passport renewal application.

Once you have the new passport, you will have to apply for a new visa for your child.

I assume the child has a TRV (Temporary Resident Visa). You can apply to extend/renew/get a new one in Canada. [This page](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-5551-applying-change-conditions-extend-your-stay-canada-paper.html) discusses extending the stay using a paper form. It's possible to apply online but you may it helpful to read through this page. Highlights include:

- Apply at least 30 days before the TRV expires but current processing times are closer to 60 days--check
- Every dependent must apply separately

Comment: A _Canadian_ visa normally does not extend beyond the passport's expiration date.